# Best practice for using Force_Index on spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, indexing, google-cloud-spanner

I have a client application which querys data in Spanner..

Lets say I have a table with 10 columns and my client application can search on a combination of columns.. Lets say I've added 5 indexes to optimise searching.

According to https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sql-best-practices#secondary-indexes
it says:

> In this scenario, Spanner automatically uses the secondary index SingersByLastName when executing the query (as long as three days have passed since database creation; see A note about new databases). However, it's best to explicitly tell Spanner to use that index by specifying an index directive in the FROM clause:

And also https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#index-directive suggests

> When you use SQL to query a Spanner table, Spanner automatically uses any indexes that are likely to make the query more efficient. As a result, you don't need to specify an index for SQL queries. However, for queries that are critical for your workload, Google advises you to use FORCE_INDEX directives in your SQL statements for more consistent performance.

Both links suggest **YOU** (The developer) should be supplying `Force_Index` on yours queries.. This means I now need business logic in my client to say something like:

```
If (object.SearchTermOne)
   queryBuilder.IndexToUse = "Idx_SearchTermOne"
```

This feels like I'm essentially trying to do the job of the optimiser by setting the index to use.. It also means if I add an extra index I need a code change to make use of it

So what are the best practices when it comes to using `Force_Index` in spanner queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use the `Force_Index` as described in the documentation at this time.

> This feels like I'm essentially trying to do the job of the optimiser by setting the index to use..

I feel the same.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#index-directive

> Note: The query optimizer requires up to three days to collect the databases statistics required to select a secondary index for a SQL query. During this time, Cloud Spanner will not automatically use any indexes.

As noted in this note, even if an amount of data is added that would allow the index to function effectively, it may take up to three days for the optimizer to figure it out.
Queries during that time will probably be full scans.
If you want to prevent this other than using `Force_Index`, you will need to run `ANALYZE` DDL manually.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/a-technical-overview-of-cloud-spanners-query-optimizer

But none of this changes the fact that we are essentially trying to do the optimizer's job...